# How to make Django QuerySet bulk delete() more efficient

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Setup:
Django 1.1.2, MySQL 5.1

Problem:

```
Blob.objects.filter(foo = foo) \
            .filter(status = Blob.PLEASE_DELETE) \
            .delete()
```

This snippet results in the ORM first generating a `SELECT * from xxx_blob where ...` query, then doing a `DELETE from xxx_blob where id in (BLAH);` where BLAH is a ridiculously long list of id's. Since I'm deleting a large amount of blobs, this makes both me and the DB very unhappy.

Is there a reason for this? I don't see why the ORM can't convert the above snippet into a single DELETE query. Is there a way to optimize this without resorting to raw SQL?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not without writing your own custom SQL or managers or something; they are apparently working on it though.

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9519

Answer (score 53):

For those who are still looking for an efficient way to bulk delete in django, here's a possible solution:

The reason `delete()` may be so slow is twofold: 1) Django has to ensure cascade deleting functions properly, thus looking for foreign key references to your models; 2) Django has to handle pre and post-save signals for your models.

If you know your models don't have cascade deleting or signals to be handled, you can accelerate this process by resorting to the private API `_raw_delete` as follows:

```
queryset._raw_delete(queryset.db)
```

More details in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/). Please note that Django already tries to make a good handling of these events, though using the raw delete is, in many situations, much more efficient.

Comment: Django can made this as a public function from queryset as `bulk_delete`, isn't it? Why is it not done? Any high level reasons? And those who use `bulk_create` is well aware that signals won't work. May be just for cascade delete?

Comment: This works for me. Main caveat as mentioned is dependent models ("cascade delete") - as long as it's a top-most kind of table with no dependencies, this works, and works really fast.

Comment: @Babu the reasons are discussed [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9519)

Comment: I had to use this because an exception raised in a model's `__init__`. It seems unreasonably difficult to do this, but suggestion works.

Comment: This is not true as of Django 3.2 / 4.x. It seems the `delete()` does proper bulk deletion automatically.

Comment: bulk_delete() in Django 4.2.x still shows the behavior described by OP, although you generally need to delete > 100 objects to see multiple DELETE queries issued.

Answer (score 14):

[Bulk delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects) is already part of django

> Keep in mind that this will, whenever possible, be executed purely in SQL

Comment: The Queryset.delete() behaves as how the OP described.

Comment: It is still inefficient and results in `OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`

Comment: Bulk - in this context - means that one light-weight SQL query is executed on the server based on WHERE condition. Django ORM's `delete()` does not act like this.

Comment: the link open a 404 page on djangoproject, was it removed?

Comment: The link pointed to a Django 1.4 doc page, which are long gone. Here is the corresponding page for the current version: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

Comment: @KrisKumler not any more it doesn't. If there are no cascades and no signal listeners, then it does a single DELETE statement.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa it does now, if it is safe for it to do so

Comment: This is not true as of Django 3.2 / 4.x. It seems the delete() does proper bulk deletion.