# django database delete specific number of entries

Tags: python, django, django-database

How to delete specific number of entries from the database?
I did something like this

```
EntriesToDelete=Statusmessages.objects.filter(time__lt=date)[:30000]
EntriesToDelete.delete()
```

But I get an error which says:
`AssertionError. Cannot use 'limit' or 'offset' with delete`.

How can I specify the number of entries to be deleted.

Comment: You can accelerate this process by using: _raw_delete. Here is related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36935536/11280799 . Please read limitations and drawbacks of this method carefully.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
pks = (Statusmessages.objects
       .filter(time__lt=date)
       .values_list('pk')[:30000])
Statusmessages.objects.filter(pk__in=pks).delete()
```

Comment: I used something similar and looped over it to maintain prevent the memory usage of the DB from going to wild when deleting millions of rows

Comment: Nice.  You probably also need 'flat=True' in the values_list call.

Comment: MariaDB/Mysql both don't like this - you get ```django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: (1235, "This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")```.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```py
Statusmessages.objects.filter(pk__in=Statusmessages.objects.filter(time__lt=date).values_list('pk', flat=True)[:30000]).delete()
```

use `flat=True`, if not then is a tuple and raise exception:

```bash
{NotSupportedError}(1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: (1235, "This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")
```

Force evaluate the list of ids with list().
Here's an example:

```py
sessions_to_delete = LoginSession.objects.filter(user=self.userProfile)[3:]
pks_of_sessions_to_delete = list(sessions_to_delete.values_list("pk", flat=True))
LoginSession.objects.filter(pk__in=pks_of_sessions_to_delete).delete()
```