# Iterating over large querysets in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How do you efficiently iterate over a large queryset (records in the millions) with Django?

I'm trying to delete several million records that I can't do with a simple bulk SQL DELETE statement because the transaction would consume too much server memory. So I'm attempting to write a Python script to group ~10000 individual DELETE statements in a transaction.

My script looks like:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.conf import settings

settings.DEBUG = False

qs = MyModel.objects.filter(some_criteria=123)
total = qs.count()
i = 0
transaction.set_autocommit(False)
for record in qs.iterator():
    i += 1
    if i == 1 or not i % 100 or i == total:
        print('%i of %i %.02f%%: %s' % (i + 1, total, (i + 1) / float(total) * 100, record))
    record.delete()
    if not i % 1000:
        transaction.commit()
transaction.commit()
```

This runs fine for the first 2000 records, but then errors with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1512, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1512, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 96, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/project/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 96, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: named cursor isn't valid anymore
```

How do I fix this error? I'm using PostgreSQL as my db backend.

Google finds very few have run into this error, and mentions no solutions specifically for Django. I've read that adding `hold=True` to the cursor call my fix it, but it's unclear how to set that through Django's ORM.

I've attempted to add a try/except to catch and continue the query, but that hasn't worked. As the traceback doesn't even include my code, I'm not specifically sure which line is triggering the exception.

Comment: to delete with limit check this link out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248593/django-database-delete-specific-number-of-entries

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs after 2000 record because this is the default `chunk_size` for iterator. After these are deleted, the iterator doesn't know where to continue from.

I would use pagination for this task.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db.models import Subquery

qs = MyModel.objects.filter(some_criteria=123)
paginator = Paginator(qs, 10000)

for page_num in reversed(paginator.page_range):
    MyModel.objects.filter(
        pk__in=Subquery(paginator.page(page_num).object_list.values('pk'))
    ).delete()
```

Here we go over the pages in reverse order to avoid issues similar to the one you get with `iterator`.

We can't call `delete` directly on the `object_list` because it's not allowed with sliced querysets, so we get the `pk`s of the objects on the page and filter against them before deleting. The `Subquery` saves us from one additional query per iteration.