# Remove ForeignKey relationship

Tags: django

I want to remove the relationship between BUser and Profile:

Since the ForeignKey doesn't allow null values I have to iterate (performance is awful!) like this to remove all the relations:

```
for u in user.profile_set.all(): 
    u.delete()



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('BUser')

class BUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
```

There is another way to delete all the relations [with a better performance]?
I've tried with:

```
obj.transparentprofile_set = None
obj.transparentprofile_set.clear()
obj.transparentprofile_set.empty()
```

but, like I said, since there's not `null=True` in the ForeignKey I can't use them.

Comment: Are you looking for `user.profile_set.all().delete()`?..

Comment: For bulk delete in Dajngo [How to make Django QuerySet bulk delete() more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867852/how-to-make-django-queryset-bulk-delete-more-efficient)

Comment: Would you like to keep the profiles without any link to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You may use my way, instead touching related model via dotted ORM childs etc `objects.childs_set`, its more clear and human readable code:

```
# Get user instance
user = User.objects.get(pk=<uid>)
# Remove profiles
Profile.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
```

Also, you need remember about `related_name` Model parameter, so instead `profile_set` you can use:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.Foreignkey(
        to=User,
        related_name='profiles'
    )

    # Use related name alias in code
    profiles = user.profiles.all()
    profile = user.profiles.filter(pk=<profile_id>)
```