# How to delete 200,000 records with DJango?

Tags: django, postgresql, bulk-delete

Situation:
I have Model have a relation 1-1, sample:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_namme = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DatetimeField()
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I have a around 200,000 records.

- Languague: Python
- Framework: Django
- Database: Postgres

Question:

- How can I delete 200,000 records above with minimal cost?

Solution I have tried:

```
user_ids = Users.objects.filter(type='sample', created_date__gte='2022-11-15 08:00', created_date__lt="2022-11-15 08:30").values_list('id',flat=True)[:200000] # Fetch 200,000 user ids. 
for i, _ in enumerate(user_ids[:: 1000]):
    with transaction.atomic():
        batch_start = i * self.batch_size
        batch_end = batch_start + self.batch_size
        _, deleted = Users.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids[batch_start,batch_end]
```

**With this solution, my server use arround:**

- 600MB CPU
- 300MB RAM
- Take more 15 minutes to finish workload.

---

I wonder do anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Isn't the right answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867852/how-to-make-django-queryset-bulk-delete-more-efficient/36935536#36935536. Bulk delete all the books followed by all the users?

Comment: @RobertMoskal, Thanks for your answer, but in my case, I must filter on User Model due to legacy data (UserModel have field query + index). And in fact, my User Model has more than 1 relation one-one to another Model.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a sql statement.

Answer (score 2):

By first principles, nothing beats raw(Django query) SQL in terms of speed because it operates closest to the database!

cursor.execute(“DELETE FROM DB WHERE Column = %s”)

Or else you can do it by:

Variable = Model.objects.filter(variable=variable)

```
if Variable.exists():

    Variable.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. I have tried the solution with RawQuery

```
user_ids = Users.objects.filter(type='sample', created_date__gte='2022-11-15 08:00', created_date__lt="2022-11-15 08:30").values_list('id',flat=True)[:200000] # Fetch 200,000 user ids. 

for i in range(0, 3):
    user_ids_str = ""
    for user_id in user_ids.iterator(chunk_size=5000):
        user_ids_str += f"{user_id},"
    query = f"""
            DELETE FROM "user" WHERE "user"."id" IN ({user_ids_str});
            DELETE FROM "book" WHERE "user"."id" IN ({user_ids_str});
    """
    with transaction.atomic():
        with connection.cursor() as c:
            c.execute("SET statement_timeout = '10min';")
            c.execute(query)
```

This one can remove 600000 records and take around 10 minutes.
And the server used around:

- **CPU**: 50MB
- **RAM**: 200MB

Comment: If you are using straight sql why not do a join on the user table to delete the books and the delete all the users using the created_date criteria?  Let the database do all the work!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using straight sql why not do a join on the user table with the date criteria to delete the books and then delete all the users using the created_date criteria?  Let the database do all the work!

Even without writing the join

```
DELETE FROM "book" WHERE "user"."id" IN (select id from user where created_date >= '2022-11-15 08:00' and...)
DELETE FROM "user" WHERE created_date >= '2022-11-15 08:00' and...
```

would be better than what you have.

Comment: If you're using SQL why not let the DB cascade on its own (You'll have to ensure `ON DELETE CASCADE`, etc. are there already)? Let the database do all the work!

Comment: Some folks don't have the ability to change schema!